# How to stop docker-ce from downgrading and keep it at version 18.03?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04, docker-ce

I've installed `docker-ce` on my Ubuntu 18.4.

The version after installation is 18.03 which is good but after restarting it downgrades on its own to 17.06.

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (downgraded from 1.37)
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Wed Jun 20 21:43:51 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ce
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.8.3
  Git commit:   a04f55b
  Built:        Thu Sep 21 20:36:57 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

I need both (client and server) to stay at 18.03. Otherwise my docker images don't work.

Comment: How did you install docker-ce? Did you follow the [docker's installation docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)?

Comment: @K0pernikus Yes, I did.

Comment: I have the same issue, even tried to hold the packages. Server Engine version gets downgraded every day, and I had to apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have another package manager messing with you. In my case another version of docker was installed with **snap**. Kudos to [@grainednoise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390161/grainednoise) to figure that one out.